# WKWebView wont show doc, docx, png, txt under iOS 12 in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, ipad, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have updated from UIWebView to WKWebView. It works under iOS 13.4.1 (Simulator and iPad) and under iOS 12.4.7 in the Simulator, but the WKWebView stays white on the real iPad.

```
        WKWebViewConfiguration webConfiguration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
        webConfiguration.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = false;
        WKWebView wkWebView = new WKWebView(Bounds, webConfiguration);
        SetNativeControl(wkWebView);

        wkWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false)));
        wkWebView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use the default `WkWebViewRenderer`? Everything is set up there and you don't need to `SetNativeControl` yourself.

Comment: @MihailDuchev
var webConfiguration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
webConfiguration.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = false;
WkWebViewRenderer webViewRenderer = new WkWebViewRenderer(webConfiguration);
webViewRenderer.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false)));
webViewRenderer.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;

Like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

```
WKWebViewConfiguration webConfiguration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
webConfiguration.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = false;
WKWebView wkWebView = new WKWebView(Bounds, webConfiguration);
SetNativeControl(wkWebView);

wkWebView.LoadFileUrl(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false), new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false));
wkWebView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since recently, `UIWebView` and its renderer have been deprecated. It is preferable to use `WkWebViewRenderer`. It should come with everything that you may need in order to open these kind of files out of the box. In case that you need to customise it further, you can simple do it in its `OnElementChanged` override:

```cs
public class MyCustomWebView : WkWebViewRenderer 
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        // Customise it here
    }
}
```

This way you won't need to manually construct and initialise the `WkWebView` and add it as a native control with `SetNativeControl()` method. Everything comes built-in within this renderer.

NB: Keep in mind that if you are using the latest Xamarin.Forms version, the WebView by default inherits from `WkWebViewRenderer`, so you don't need to explicitly change it. You need to subclass the `WkWebViewRenderer`, only if you need to add additional configs, which aren't exposed in Forms.

Comment: Could you please give me a code example how my code would need to look?

Comment: If you simply want to open these kind of extensions and not have any additional modifications, update your Xamarin to the latest version (which version are you using now?) and delete your WebView renderer file.

Comment: 4.3.0.908675, but I could use 4.6.0.800. Both didn't seem to work.

Comment: Setting your issue aside, you'll need to update to latest Forms (and delete the WebView renderer), because `UIWebView` has been deprecated from Apple, and you won't be able to upload your app, because the old versions of Xamarin.Forms still have reference to it. Returning to your issue - how are you loading the files in the shared project?

Comment: 'LoadFileUrl(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false), new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false))' done the trick, but thanks for your effort